# Verifying two invocations of the same method with another method invocation in between, when order is important, in Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I thought this would work:

```
InOrder inOrder = new InOrder(mock);
inOrder.verify(mock).method1();
inOrder.verify(mock).method2();
inOrder.verify(mock).method1();
```

… but Mockito says `undesired invocation of mock.method1(). Wanted 1 time, but was 2 times.` I changed my code to this:

```
inOrder.verify(times(2), mock).method1();
inOrder.verify(mock).method2();
```

It should work, but now I do not test what I wanted to test in the first place.
Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong, or if Mockito is too limited for these kind of test?

Comment: It works. Your code calls method1 twice first and then method2.

Comment: It seems that all is ok with your first test. Can you show the code you are testing?

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong. As you say, this actually works. I have made a mistake somewhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It tested this with Mockito 1.9.5 and it works:

```
@Test
public void foo() {
    Runnable outer = Mockito.mock(Runnable.class, "outer");
    Runnable inner = Mockito.mock(Runnable.class, "inner");

    outer.run();
    inner.run();
    outer.run();

    InOrder order = Mockito.inOrder(outer, inner);
    order.verify(outer).run();
    order.verify(inner).run();
    order.verify(outer).run();
}
```

So if you aren't doing anything else wrong your code should work. What Mockito version are you using?

Comment: I have made a mistake somewhere else. The test in your answer is working. If I add another order.verify(outer).run(); beneath the last line, however, the test will fail. So, I will have to keep track of where consecutive calls to the same method occurs, and use the times() method there.

Comment: A caveat: `order.verify(mock)` works as expected when repeated. `order.verify(mock, times(n))` is greedy and fails when you have more than n calls available in the future. Mockito 1.9.5